# Symetric Encryption - Salt and IV

Tags: encryption, salt

I have been reading up on Symmetric Encryption and it appears if I want to add salt to my encryption I then would need to provide that salt value to the end user as well that wishes to decrypt the content, is this correct? Also if I wish to use an Initialization Vector(IV) I would also need to provide that to the end user that is decrypting is that correct? Or is that something that only I would need when I encrypt the content?

Comment: Salts are typically only used when hashing data, not encrypting it. The first line of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)), for example, states `a salt is random data that is used as an additional input to a one-way function that "hashes" a password or passphrase.` In symmetric encryption, the salt would serve no purpose - it would just be extra data that would be at start of the message following decryption by anyone with a valid decryption key.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the purpose of salt. I was referring to salt in the context of encrypting a string or whatever. So essentially its just a random value that can be appended to the value prior to encryption, does that sound about right?

Comment: No that does not sound right. Appending a random bytes to data prior to encryption achieves nothing. Add some more information to the question about the salt, what the reference context was. Also just hashing a password, even with a salt is insufficient to generate an encryption key, a key derivation functions such as PBKDF2 should be used.

Answer (score 2):

The IV does not need to be secret and is often prepended to the encrypted data to make it available during decryption. The IV is generally a sequence of random bytes the length of the algorithm block size.

Salt as used in the question is undefined for encryption, you need to provide more information of how the salt related to the encryption in the question. Sometimes a salt is used when deriving an encryption key from a password.